# Why is $\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathbb{R}^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^2$, but $\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: modules, tensor-products

I know that $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C}$ which is the same as $\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathbb{R}^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^2$. I also know that $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^4.$

In the second statement, the dimension adds (two-dimensional + two-dimensional gives four-dimensional). In the first statement, two-dimensional + two-dimensional gives another two-dimensional space. Why is this the case?

Comment: Tensor products multiply dimensions; and also, $\mathbb{C}$ is 1-dimensional as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.